# Apache react-router Not Found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, reactjs, mod-rewrite, react-router

I have deployed my create react app application to apache2 server.

My application root is `/var/www/html/MY_APPLICATION`.

When I tried to access as `http://MY_IP/MY_APPLICATION`, I am able to access it. But, when I am trying other routes like `http://MY_IP/MY_APPLICATION/some-other-route`, I am getting 404 Not Found.

I knew that server will search for MY_APPLICATION/some-other-route/index.html, so we need to make `.htaccess file` and use url rewriting.

I have created `.htaccess` file in the `MY_APPLICATION` where my `index.html` reside.

In that I have added the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

I have found that to enable url rewrite we must activate it by using

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I also done that.

Do I need to do anything else to make it work.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

My routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, IndexRoute, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/Root/Application';
import Home from './containers/Root/Application/Home';
import Search from './containers/Root/Application/Search';

const routes = (
    <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/:category" component={Search}/>
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Comment: Can you share you react-router config and your `package.json`
? You can configure react-router without redirect!

Comment: what do you mean by "You can configure react-router without redirect!"

Comment: use `webpack` with  `--history-api-fallback`